# How to uninstall Airflow?

Tags: pip, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am a newbie to **Airflow**. i have some trouble to remove Airflow v1.10.3 ,i am using pip3 version 8.1.1 on Ubuntu 16.04.

I already tried to remove pip with `sudo apt-get remove python3-pip` 
and `sudo apt-get remove pip3` and all his dependencies. 
and tried to remove all libraries related with Python.

But i stil have **Airflow** and his commands down in terminal.

Comment: How have you installed `Airflow`? `apt` or `pip`? You need to remove it with the same tool.

Comment: i installed with `pip` that's why i wanted to remove `pip` with all his libraries.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The command `apt-get remove pip` doesn't remove `pip`-installed libraries.To uninstall `pip`-installed libraries you need to install `pip` back and then uninstall the libraries using `pip`:

```
sudo apt install pip # or pip3

pip uninstall airflow
```

or

```
pip3 uninstall airflow
```

depending on what python version you use.

Answer (score 16):

If you are not able to uninstall with

```
pip uninstall airflow
```

Maybe the reason is for the latest versions of Airflow this command will work

```
pip uninstall apache-airflow
```

Credits to [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57694436/5476209).