# how to remove airflow install

Tags: python, ubuntu, airflow

I tried `pip uninstall airflow` and `pip3 uninstall airflow` and both return

> Cannot uninstall requirement airflow, not installed

I'd like to remove airflow completely and run clean install.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Airflow` now is `apache-airflow`.

Comment: Very useful insight